# ActiveMQ Spring Integration using MQTT topic

Tags: java, activemq-classic, mqtt, spring-jms

I am new to activemq. am create a topic in activeMQ. and am publish data through mqtt

```
mosquitto_pub   -d -t testTopic -m "test message"
```

But i got an error message

> ERROR : Message is not of expected type TextMessage.

this is my code

```
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
     if (message instanceof TextMessage) {


      }
      else
      {

        logger.error("Message is not of expected type TextMessage.");
      }
}
```

What is the actual problem? . but iam successfully send data through http to the same topic.

Any idea ...???

Comment: You need to provide more information, the full error, who is logging the error etc.

Comment: i got the problem.  in my code, the input  data is type of byte message.

Comment: but how to get actual message

Comment: http://activemq.apache.org/maven/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/command/ActiveMQBytesMessage.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in ActiveMQ Spring consumer, the http message is the type of text message and mqtt message is the type of BytesMessage. because am add some code

```
if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
                BytesMessage bm = (BytesMessage) message;
                byte data[];
                data = new byte[(int) bm.getBodyLength()];
                bm.readBytes(data);
                msgText = new String(data);
                System.out.println("Message String = "+msgText);
}
```